# i want to pass 10 records together as a list as an input to script component in SSIS

Tags: c#, web-services, ssis, script-component

In a dataflowtask , i add a source which reads the ID from a Table.
then I call a Scrip Component which calls a REST api and processes and the output is sent to a Destination.

I want to take 10 records from the source at a time to a script components  as the API takes multiple ID's at a time.
How this can be achieved in SSIS

Comment: What have you tried? There are examples online. Does it need to be done in SSIS? There are better platforms for this.

Comment: Research "SSIS Script Component asynchronous" You will have to count the number of rows flowing through your input buffer to accumulate your 10 or EndOfBuffer count and work from there